# Returning nlargest for nested sorted dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with a dataframe that lists a large amount of data that has several filtering levels if that makes sense. So my data is now sorted per state name alphabetically. Second filtering level applies to the population data per county. The filtering i have used was `df.sort_values()`. I now need to extract the highest three population county counts per state and I am at a loss how to pursue this.

So my data looks something like this (I omitted the row index here):

```
State    County    Population
Alabama  a         100
Alabama  b         50
Alabama  c         40
Alabama  d         5
Alabama  e         1
...
Wyoming  a.51      180
Wyoming  b.51      150
Wyoming  c.51      56
Wyoming  d.51      5
```

Now what I want from my dataframe is to get the highest populated counties **per** state. Not having worked with pandas much my initial guess would be to do a for. Something like this (obviously erronous):

```
list_l = []
for i in df['State'].unique(): #Get a series with every unique state listed once
    list_l.append(df[(df['State'] == i])).nlargest(3)
return list_l
```

Even when typing this I know it doesn't fully make sense but I am not sure how to explain it better. Hope someone can help.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry are you after `df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(3)`?

Comment: You use the index from the above code snippet to index back into the main df: `df.loc[df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(3).index.get_level_values(1)]`

Comment: Hi Ed, yes that's what I'm after. I'm still getting my head around how to think pandas.

Comment: don't forget to exclude the sumlev == 40 rows ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
s = df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(3)
print (s)
State     
Alabama  0    100
         1     50
         2     40
Wyoming  5    180
         6    150
         7     56
Name: Population, dtype: int64
```

Then [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) from second level and select by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
print (s.index.get_level_values(1))
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')

print (df.ix[s.index.get_level_values(1)])
     State County  Population
0  Alabama      a         100
1  Alabama      b          50
2  Alabama      c          40
5  Wyoming   a.51         180
6  Wyoming   b.51         150
7  Wyoming   c.51          56
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems so simple, yet I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours... I love this community!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`df.sort_values('State', 'Population')`

After that, you could use

`df.groupby('State').head(3)`

In short:

```
s = df.sort_values(['State','Population'],ascending=False).groupby('State').head(3)
```

Comment: Yes, I have used this, but it only sorts my Dataframe. I need to extract the highest three populations per state. I have implemented Jezraels solution and it works like a charm.

Comment: the .head(3) will extract it.